# kvm kernel module not loaded

Tags: package-management, kvm-virtualization

I installed KVM on ubuntu 16.04 and when I run virt manager it shows this message:

Warning: KVM is not available. This may mean the KVM package is not installed, or the KVM kernel modules are not loaded. Your virtual machines may perform poorly

[image]

Comment: Do you have VirtualBox VM open alongside virt?
I found that running both of them alongside each other causes an issue.

Answer (score 5):

You either haven't installed qemu-kvm or you don't have virtualization enabled from BIOS.

Run this to make sure that you have KVM modules installed:

`sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm`

And run this to make sure you have virtualization enabled from BIOS (If you don't then enable that):

`grep vmx /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: as you say i did it, and then i open **virt-manager**  now it show me **ERROR: No Active Connection to install on**

Comment: @harsh, what hardware do you have brand/model? I have seen similar case when VT is enabled but virtualbox couldn't detect it. (an HP Elite Pro) We fixed that by upgrading EFI/BIOS firmware.

Comment: Enabling virtual in the bios was correct. There were Advanced settings in CPU and North Bridge for virtualization. On Ubuntu 18.04, kvm is no longer a package.  `apt install qemu-kvm` worked. On AMD Rizen 1700, the grep for vmx did not work. In /proc/cpuinfo, vmx is for Intel, smx is for AMD. The grep command should be: `grep "vmx\|svm" /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: I get `Package kvm is not available, but is referred to by another package.`

Answer (score 0):

For the users of Ubuntu 20.04 just run:

```
apt install qemu-kvm
```